# Remove BottomNavigationView Icons and center title

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a bottom navigation view with 3 items. I want to only have centered text for each tab, and would therefore like to fully remove icons (not only make them transparent).

How can I remove Icons and center the titles?

This is what I have:
[image]
This is what I want:
[image]

My code: (Prefer solution in XML)

```
<merge  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
            android:background="@color/navigation"
            app:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/home">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_today"
        android:title="@string/today">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_you"
        android:title="@string/you">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just use

```
android:paddingBottom="16dp" //(any dp you want)
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, for me

```
private int baselineHeight = 0;

private void removeIcons(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) (menuView.getChildAt(i));
        BaselineLayout baseline = (BaselineLayout) itemView.getChildAt(1);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) baseline.getLayoutParams();
        baselineHeight = baselineHeight > 0 ? baselineHeight : (menuView.getHeight() + baseline.getHeight()) / 2;
        layoutParams.height = baselineHeight;
        baseline.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

just call it in **onCreate()** in your Activity and pass your **BottomNavigationView** as parameter.

If you don't want to clutter your Activities or Fragments with excess code and you want this present in your **layout XML** you can create a **custom View** that **extends BottomNavigationView** and call this function in **onLayout() override**.

Answer (score 0):

Add fix height to your bottom sheet and set bottom padding. Works for me.

```
   android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:paddingBottom="20dp"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this property of bottom navigationview to hide the text and it will automatically centered your icons and i think ou do not use the minHeight property sir.
`app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I think you have miss understood, i' trying to hide the icons and center the text. Not the other way around. Your solution removes the text which I am trying to keep