# BottomNavigationView with text only

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Is it possible to remove icon padding and center text vertically in BottomNavigationView from material library (or at least change the height of navbar without title cutting)?
Want to achieve the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCFOV.jpg).
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521959/remove-bottomnavigationview-icons-and-center-title

Comment: android:icon="@android:color/transparent" in menu xml file

Comment: bottom navigation is made for maximum 5 or 6 not for a to z use reyclerView in the bottom of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tab layout instead you can easily achieve that. Here is the link https://material.io/components/tabs